# Mysql insert in two tables where the first table has foreign key and update the first table

Tags: php, mysql, database

This I have in db if i insert in to BMW car from brands for example.How i update the id_make whith the id from the BMW with sql.(I know is a huge mess in code and no aligment)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQQg1.png

This is my form:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Car:</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body ">
        <form action="index.php?page=carlist" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="marca">Marca:</label>
                <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" name="marca" placeholder="Marca" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#marca"> -->
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" placeholder="
                                   <?php
                        if (!isset($brd['name']))
                        {
                            echo "Brand";
                        } else
                            echo $brd['name'];
                        ?>" name="marca" readonly="readonly">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable">
                            <?php foreach ($brds as $brd)
                            { ?>
                                <li><a href='#'><?php echo $brd['name']; ?></a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /btn-group -->
                </div>
                <!-- /input-group -->
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="model">Model:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="model" placeholder="Model">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="color">Color:</label>
                <input type="test" class="form-control" name="color" placeholder="Color">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="release_date">Release date:</label>

                <div class=" date">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="release_date" placeholder="Release date"
                           id='release_date'>
                    <!-- <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span> -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Value">Value:</label>
                <input type="test" class="form-control" name="value" placeholder="Value">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" name="addCar" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add car">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

(The php from the input on brand is to show all brands from db )

When i select the brand from the list and put the model ,color, value ,release date I press Add car then php makes the connection on db then i insert on table models the model of the car and then i need to add the id from the brands witch car is selected on the list and then update the models id_make with the id of the car.

Comment: You should rearrange your question.. You lost me on the road..

Comment: I think that a code example would make your question easier to understand.

Comment: You should rewrite that question, its unreadable
You probably need something called ON UPDATE CASCADE http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74627/difference-between-on-delete-cascade-on-update-cascade-in-mysql

Comment: I have the clasic insert with a single table.I put CASCADE there.

Comment: I must admit I am also lost on the road @MateiMihai

Comment: Ok. 
I have 2 tables brands and models on brands i have AUDI with id=1 and BMW with id=2 and on models i have 0 things ,i insert the models with that form that I put there .When I select AUDI and i put the model TT(for example) and color blue, when i click on Add car its inserts the car  color and brand on the table table but the table has one more column with name in_brand witch that need to be 1 because AUDI has id 1 but how i make the id_brand to add(update) the id from the car on the id_brand in same time when i add the car model and other things .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to request the ID of the make you just inserted using:

```php
mysql_insert_id();
```

With that you get the ID of the record just inserted, and use that ID for the make in your other table.

Comment: Thanks man it worked with the id bun i not used mysql_insert_id().The ideea was good.